# build.gradle package name for a .co.uk domain name

Tags: android, gradle, subdomain

I am building an Android app for a domain that is `https://test.company.co.uk` (example domain name)

Normally in the `build.gradle` file, we set the `applicationId` to be the domain backwards (so `test.company.com` would have an applicationId of `com.company.test`)

I have tries setting the value to both `co.uk.company.test` and `uk.co.company.test` but for both I get the following error

> /app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml:24:
>   error: attribute 'package' in  tag is not a valid Android
>   package name: 'co.uk.company.test'

What is the correct way to specify the applicationId for a non .com address/domain?

Comment: Silly question, but does your `src` package structure also match what you're specifying in the manifest?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDodd - do you mean the AndroidManifest.xml file? I can see this in there `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.placeholder">` - is that what determines the pattern of the valid package structure?

Comment: Let's say you want your package name to be `uk.co.example`, does your folder structure look like `src/main/java/uk/co/example`?

Comment: This is an 'out of the box' app and so far, I have always ben able to add the applicationId as com.company.test but now need to associate it to a .co.uk domain also. Nothing else has changed in the project structure

Comment: @MichaelDodd thanks Michael - it was the src package structure. If you want to add your comment as an answer, I can mark it as the accepted one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package name you specify within `AndroidManifest.xml` must match the package structure of your source. So for example, if you want to define your application with the package name `uk.co.company.test`, the folder structure of your application must follow accordingly:

```
/src
|--> /main
  |--> /java
    |--> /uk
      |--> /co
        |--> /company
          |--> /test
```

This will be picked up by the IDE and compiler as a Java source set containing the package `uk.co.company.test`, which can then be referenced in the manifest.